# How do I clear datepicker and input number after onClick react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to reset the values of datepicker and input fileds after filter my bookings on a onClick call so that the user have to make a new onClick with a empty input field/datepicker every time. This is what I have so far:

```
const intaialValue = {
  date: null,
  time: null,
}

const Bookings = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState()
  const [time, setTime] = useState([])


  const getBookingsDateAndTime = async () => {
    const response = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/bookings/date/${moment(new Date(date)).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}/${time}`);
    console.log(response.data);

    setDate(response);
    setTime(response);
    setBookings(response.data.data.bookings);

    setDate(intaialValue)
  }


   <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={() => getBookingsDateAndTime()}>Filter</button>
```

But the fields doesn't clear when onClick is called from the Filter button:

[image: This fields dosn't clear when onClick on filter button]

Comment: I think you aren't passing the right value to setDate and setTime. What does your console.log print ?

Comment: It prints this to console: http://localhost:4000/bookings/date/2020-10-20/21:00, I want to clear datepicker and clear input field for time when onClick.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set **date** and **time** to empty as they are invalid format for date and time values display on UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an useEffect hook on bookings or state variable which you use to set on response from api. when bookings is set then setDate() null or empty.

useEffect(()=>{setDate()},[bookings])